# How can I covert .tsv file to xlsx file using vbscript?

Tags: vba, vbscript

I need to covert a .tsv file into .xlsx format. Is there a way to do that using vbscript? I tried to find that online but was not able to find what I actually need. I am very new to VBScript. It will be great if someone can help me with this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does *convert a .tsv file to .xlsx format* mean specifically? I'm guessing that a `.tsv` file means `tab-separated value`, but you've not asked any sort of actual question here. What have you tried so far to do this yourself? What specific issue are you having difficulties with?

Comment: @KenWhite I know we can convert .tsv file into excel file by dragging the .tsv file inside the excel. But I need to do it using vbscript. I know there is a function objWorkSheet.QueryTables.Add that can be used to convert .tsv into excel but there are various parameter to be passed into it. So I need help in that.

Comment: See [Workbooks.Open](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.Workbooks.Open), look for parameter `Format` (1)  in the `Remarks` section

Comment: None of that information is in your question, which is why I asked. You should [edit] to add it there.

Comment: Excel can record macros. So record doing QueryTables.Add and you'll get VBA code that needs to be converted from named to positional parameters for VBS (Alt + T, M, R). Or read the help file in excel (Alt + F11, F1). Or use object browser `Function Add(Connection, Destination As Range, [Sql]) As QueryTable` (Alt + F11, F2).

Comment: Thank you @Noodles . I will definitely try this and let you know my feedback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In its simplest form this will work. DisplayAlerts suppresses the save prompts and Visible is only needed if you want to see it happen. This will create its own Excel instance, so it shouldn't interfere with any Excel instance currently open.

```
Option Explicit

Dim objExcel : set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
objExcel.Application.DisplayAlerts = false
objExcel.Visible = true
objExcel.Workbooks.OpenText "c:\users\TEST\desktop\tab_delimited.tsv" ,,,1,,,,,,,True,"|"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "c:\users\TEST\desktop\tab_delimited.xlsx", 51
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close
set objExcel = Nothing
```